# iPhone 4: Touches works on simulator but not on device

Tags: iphone, touches

I'm developing a universal application, I actually tested in on:

- iPad: Simulator OK - Device OK
- iPhone 3G: Simulator OK - Device OK
- iPhone 3GS: Simulator OK - Device OK
- iPhone 4: Simulator OK - **Device NOT working**

the application don't respond to any touch input, I tried to put some breakpoints into touchBegun,touchMoves,touchEnded, they are never called... any idea ?

Comment: Are you running the same iOS version on 3Gs / iPhone 4? If you start a new hello world application with just a button and a label, will that work if it is a univeral binary? If not, will it work if the binary is iPhone only?

Comment: Yes, it's running the same version. I tried to create an empty, universal app and it works.

Comment: HOW MANY DEVICES DO YOU HAVE !!! :O ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue simply disappeared this morning after a reboot... iOS instability ? nvm

Comment: For future reference, here's the steps I use to solve a problem like that: 1. Clean all targets, rebuild 2. Delete app from phone, rebuild 3. reboot phone 4. give xcode the finger 5. ask on SO